# How do I hide a tableView searchBar

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to have a searchBar in the tableView that is hidden by default, but if the user pulls down it appears.

So I have used the following code to implement this but when the view is first displayed the searchBar is momentarily visible and I would like avoid this brief flash.  Adding `self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)` to the `viewDidLoad()` method does not have any affect.  Note that the tableView is behind a navigation controller which is why setting the Y offset to 0 effectively hides the searchBar behind the navigation bar. Any idea how to make sure the tableView's headerView is hidden when the view is first be displayed.

I have considered simply removing the headerView but then the user can't drag down to access it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44)
    if let tv = self.tableView {
        if let headerView = tv.tableHeaderView {
            headerView.addSubview(searchBar)
        } else {
            FLOG("No table header view is available so create one!")
            let headerView = UIView()
            let width: CGFloat = tv.frame.size.width
            headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 44);
            tv.tableHeaderView = headerView
            tv.tableHeaderView!.addSubview(searchBar)
        }
    }        
}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    dispatch_after(0, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an ordering issue with `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidLoad`. As I understand, `viewWillAppear` gets called every time a view will be drawn and added to the view hierarchy, whereas viewDidLoad gets called when a VC loads its subview for the first time.

So, I suppose on your first run the view loads via the `mainQueue` with `viewDidLoad` which places your search bar at (0,44), then `viewWillAppear` gets called but actually causes a brief visual blip due to the call to move the table's offset on the mainQueue. But on subsequent calls, since `viewDidLoad` has already happened, only `viewWillAppear` gets called. And since the search bar doesn't first start at (0,44) and then needs to move to (0,0), there's no blip.

Rather than directly defining the frame for the search bar, try calling `sizeToFit` on it after adding it to the tableHeader. Secondly, I don't believe you have to instantiate the header view, just set it equal to the searchbar. Lastly, take the `contentOffset` call out of the dispatch_queue, it should be handled correctly by `viewWillAppear` as is.

I went deep into UISearchController for iOS8 recently, and documented the journey (in part at least). For the code I used, [here's a link to the implementation file](https://github.com/spacedrabbit/LeagueOfBlargl/blob/v0.2/LeagueOfBlargl/LeagueOfBlargl/SearchRiotTVController.m) and the [corresponding write-up](http://catthoughts.ghost.io/zq-league-of-blargl-day-2/) I did. It's in ObjC, so you'll need to do a little translation. But it looks like:

```
 self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.filteredResultsTableViewController];
 self.searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar; 

 // other code ...

 [self.searchBar sizeToFit];

 // other code ...

 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

Comment: Thanks, however when I call 'contentOffset' in 'viewWillAppear' directly it does not work at all. I found another post where they got it working by using 'dispatch'. This seems to be new behaviour for iOS8.x.  I'll have a look at the other suggestions shortly.

Comment: BTW you are correct in that 'viewDidLoad' gets called once and 'viewWillAppear' gets called whenever the view becomes visible.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that later I add another view to the headerView which is why I don't use the searchBar itself.  However this should not affect the display.

Comment: ahhh gotcha, thanks for the `viewWillAppear` info. Have you tried to instantiate the searchbar/header without explicitly defining its frame (I think the header has an intrinsic size of what you're already defining)? also, adding a tableview to a nav controller defines is presentation context to the bounds visible bounds of the the navcontroller, so it knows to take into account the size of the navbar and/or status bar. defining it's frame might not be taking this into account, so it's being positioned according to a different coordinate than it should be.

Comment: I guess my hypothesis is that since it's only happening once when it's initially loaded, that suggests it has to be something that's occurring only once related to positioning. We'll just have to narrow down what that might be